# How to get all sub categories active and inactive

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to know how I can get all active and inactive category children's

This code get me only the active childrens.

```
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);        
$childCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()        
    ->addIdFilter($parentCategory->getChildren())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', $categoryName)
    ->getFirstItem()    // Assuming your category names are unique ??
;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Hello Check below code may be help you

```
    <?php
$id=10;
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', array('in' => array(0,1)))
  ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $id);

echo count($collection);
?>
```

Comment: This works but the `is_active` filter is useless. is active can only be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late but I just came across this function, getChildrenCategoriesWithInactive, so now I do:

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', 'mycategoryname');
$_subcategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getChildrenCategoriesWithInactive();
if($_subcategories):
     foreach ($_subcategories as $_subcategory):
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

This what I did

```
$query = "SELECT cce.entity_id FROM catalog_category_entity as cce left join "
        . "catalog_category_entity_varchar as ccev on cce.entity_id = ccev.entity_id "
        . "where cce.parent_id = :parent_id "
        . "and ccev.attribute_id = 41 and ccev.value = :ccev_value";
$values = array('parent_id' => $id,
                'ccev_value' => $categoryName,                 
        );                    

$result = $readConnection->fetchAll($query,$values);  
if (count($result) > 0){
    return $result[0]['entity_id'];
}else{
    return '';
}
```